# Getting today's date using pandas to_datetime version 0.23.4

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

In older version of pandas when i do

```
>>> x = pd.to_datetime('today')
>>> x
Timestamp('2019-03-28 00:00:00.0')
```

However when running on pandas 0.23.4

```
>>> x = pd.to_datetime('today')
>>> x
Timestamp('2019-03-28 18:13:45.678015')
```

How do i get today's date with the time set to midnight like in the old version??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tested in pandas 0.24.2 and same problem.

Solution is use [`Timestamp.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Timestamp.floor.html):

```
x = pd.to_datetime('today').floor('d')
print (x)
2019-03-28 00:00:00
```